# Can i sort guids list and make binary search?

Tags: c#, guid, binary-search

I have class `Value`:

```
class Value
{
   public Guid Guid {get;set;}
   public double Val {get;set;}
}
```

So, if i have two big lists of `Value`, how can i sort it and then use BinarySearch?

Can i do it?
Thank you!

Comment: @ upvoter : Make sure the question is valid before casting vote. The above code wont compile

Comment: I edit double Value to Val;

Comment: and I wouldn't name that property as Guid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Summary:

If you have a list of `Value` and you want to sort your list according the `Guid`  you have two possiblities. Either you sort the list explicitly by the property you want or you implement `IComparable<Value>`

```
var orderedList = list.OrderBy(i => i.Guid);
```

the other case is:

```
public class Value: IComparable<Value>
{
    public int CompareTo(Value other)
    {
        if(other == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return Guid.CompareTo(other.Guid);
    }
    //[...]
}
```

then you can sort:

```
var orderedList = list.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
```

Then when you want to perform binary searching just apply following line:

```
int index = orderedList.BinarySearch(new Value{ Guid = guidToSearchFor });
```

## Example:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<Value> list = new List<Value>
        {
            new Value() { Guid = Guid.NewGuid() },
            new Value() { Guid = Guid.NewGuid() },
            new Value() { Guid = Guid.NewGuid() },
            new Value() { Guid = Guid.NewGuid() }
        };
    
        var orderedList = list.OrderBy(i => i).ToList();
        int index = orderedList.BinarySearch(new Value{ Guid = list[2].Guid });
        Console.WriteLine(index);
    }
}

public class Value: IComparable<Value>
{
    public int CompareTo(Value other)
    {
        if(other == null)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        return Guid.CompareTo(other.Guid);
    }
    
    public Guid Guid {get;set;}
    public double Val {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: The question is not solely about sorting. From my reading of the question the more important part is the binary search ***after*** the sort.

Comment: @Enigmativity. thanks. I have added the part with binary-searching.

Comment: I had to add `.ToList()` to `orderedList` to get this to compile. And when I run it with a valid `Guid` for `guidToSearchFor` I get an `InvalidOperationException` "Failed to compare two elements in the array.".

Comment: @Enigmativity Try the example I have added, It works.

Answer (score 0):

Let `List<Value> valList = new List<Value>();` be your List of `Value` Then you can sort them based on property `Val` like the following:

```
 valList = valList.OrderBy(x => x.Val).ToList();
```

Comment: and can i use BinarySearch with Guid by key?

Comment: The question is not solely about sorting. From my reading of the question the more important part is the binary search ***after*** the sort.